# Op-amp limiter circuit with Zener diodes

Tags: operational-amplifier, current-limiting

I am new to electronics and we have this course for university.

What is the theoretical analysis for this circuit? How can I find the Vin and the Vout? I think there is more than one case.

The circuit is:

[image: limiter]

Comment: If the zeners were not there, what would the response be? What would happen when the voltage across the 1k feedback resistor reaches the zener breakdown voltage?

Comment: Hint: Use virtual short to determine node voltages at the op-amps inputs.

Comment: Think of this circuit of as an inverting amplifier where R is R1 and the combination of D1, D2 and 1 k resistor are R2. Analyze the circuit at the two input polarities.

Comment: I think that's one of the answers to why we see 741s cropping up in projects, they are used in teaching uni courses! Sigh!

Comment: Can you analyse the circuit without D1 and D2? The opamp has feedback, so what will its -ve input voltage be? Imagine the zeners are not conducting. What is the output voltage as a function of input voltage. Over what range of output voltages will the no zener conduction assumption hold true? Now imagine they're conducting. What range of output voltages will that be true for? What are the input conditions to get that?

Comment: A warm welcome to the site. Please note that it's not a free homework-answering service or on-line technical encyclopaedia, copied out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your question shows you've already done as much as you possibly could - which yours doesn't, I'm afraid. You cannot be 'new to electronics' when studying circuits of that standard. Please edit your question and greatly improve it. Show your own work and own findings in considerable detail. The better the quality of your question, the better the quality of the answers it will attract. Again, welcome.

Comment: Did you ever find the solution?/ Βρήκες ποτέ τη λύση;